# BigQuery SQL how to get total count when using LIMIT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I use `LIMIT 10` in a SQL query (using BigQuery), is there a way to also return the total count?

For example, 100 rows exist. How can I query to return the first 10 but also display to users how many rows are available in total without doing a separate `count(id)` aggregate query?

Comment: you concern about the execution plan of your SQL query, right?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Mikhail's answer, you may want to do this to see the count of the unique values in a grouped query. In the following example, there are 10 unique values of R, but you only want to see the the first 4, along with the count of the unique rows. I also added showing the count for each group and overall count of every row. (Standard SQL below)

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 AS r    
)
SELECT 
  r,
  SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY r ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS CountOfAllUniqueRows,
  COUNT(r) AS CountOfEachR,
  SUM(COUNT(R)) OVER (ORDER BY r ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS CountOfAllRows
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY r
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 4
```

And giving the results of:

```
r   CountOfAllUniqueRows    CountOfEachR    CountOfAllRows
1   10                      8               68
2   10                      6               68
3   10                      7               68
4   10                      6               68
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why you would wanted to do this  - maybe because of cost - so you avoid second scan - anyway - Below "trick' might work for you.
While getting only as many rows as you wish  - you also getting total rows count but within each and every output row - So you need to handle this on your own when displaying this to user

> With BigQuery Legacy SQL:

```
SELECT 
  r, cnt
FROM (
  SELECT 
    r,
    COUNT(r) OVER() AS cnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS line
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS r),
    (SELECT 2 AS r),
    (SELECT 3 AS r),
    (SELECT 4 AS r),
    (SELECT 5 AS r),
    (SELECT 6 AS r),
    (SELECT 7 AS r),
    (SELECT 8 AS r),
    (SELECT 9 AS r),
    (SELECT 10 AS r)
)
WHERE line <= 4
```

or

```
SELECT 
  r,
  cnt
FROM (
  SELECT r
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS r),
    (SELECT 2 AS r),
    (SELECT 3 AS r),
    (SELECT 4 AS r),
    (SELECT 5 AS r),
    (SELECT 6 AS r),
    (SELECT 7 AS r),
    (SELECT 8 AS r),
    (SELECT 9 AS r),
    (SELECT 10 AS r)
) AS YourTable
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS r),
    (SELECT 2 AS r),
    (SELECT 3 AS r),
    (SELECT 4 AS r),
    (SELECT 5 AS r),
    (SELECT 6 AS r),
    (SELECT 7 AS r),
    (SELECT 8 AS r),
    (SELECT 9 AS r),
    (SELECT 10 AS r)
) rows
LIMIT 4
```

> With BigQuery Standard SQL:

*Don't forget to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>*

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 AS r UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 AS r    
)
SELECT 
  r,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM YourTable) AS cnt
FROM YourTable
LIMIT 4
```

In all cases result is

```
r   cnt  
1   10   
2   10   
3   10   
4   10
```

Comment: Beware - this won't run as expected: The LIMIT is applied before the OVER(), hence rows will be "4". (Use a subselect instead)

Comment: found reference to this behavior - https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=424

Comment: This works, but the count is done on a single machine in legacy and cannot scale.