# Pagination for BigQuery via nodejs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is an automated pagination between nodejs and BigQuery built into the library, which means, if used correctly, then nodejs creates multiple requests transparently in the background if my query returns too many results for one.

While this is a great feature, I wonder how to implement an actual pagination if I want to only query for a very limited number of rows in the first instance, and then potentially have a look on pages two or three.

```
  let query = `SELECT * FROM  \`${projectId}.${docDataset}.${docTable}\` t
      WHERE (customerId = @myCustomerId)
      ORDER BY documentId ASC
      LIMIT 5`;

  const options = {
    query: query,
    location: location,
    params: { myCustomerId: customerId }
  };

  const [job] = await client.createQueryJob(options);
  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

  debugLog(`Query : ${query} -- Results: ${rows.length}`);
  console.log(rows);
  console.log(job);
```

This query returns the first five rows, as expected. But how do I know if there are more rows, and how many? Neither `rows` nor `job` contains the *totalrows*.

I certainly could query twice; once for the number of results, and then for the actual, limited number of results.

But that seems a bit complex for a modern, API enabled database. Is there a simple solution?  Maybe a `totalRows` attribute?

Comment: Just found a potential answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096720/bigquery-sql-how-to-get-total-count-when-using-limit

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @hey, you can refer to the sample query provided as a possible solution for this problem in this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096720/bigquery-sql-how-to-get-total-count-when-using-limit)

```
WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT 1 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS r UNION ALL
SELECT 10 AS r
)
SELECT
r,
SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY r ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS CountOfAllUniqueRows,
COUNT(r) AS CountOfEachR,
SUM(COUNT(R)) OVER (ORDER BY r ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS CountOfAllRows
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY r
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 5
```

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.